# jsp session implicit object is throwing null pointer exception when calling it from servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am developing an application using jsp and servlet, I am facing a problem using session implicit object in jsp.
What I am doing is I am setting certain attributes in session object in servlets, and then I am forwarding a response to a jsp page. Now I want to access those session attributes in my jsp page but on doing this it is throwing a null pointer exception.
Here is my code:-

This is my servlet,

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    con=Connector.myCon();
    u=request.getParameter("userName");
    p=request.getParameter("password");
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("userName",u); 
    session.setAttribute("userType",userType);
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

and this is my jsp

```
<%
    session=request.getSession();
    String s = (String) application.getAttribute("name");
    System.out.println(s);
    String userName = (String)session.getAttribute("userName");
    if (userName == null) {
        //request.setAttribute("Error", "Session has ended.  Please logenter code herein.");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request
                .getRequestDispatcher("index.hmtl");
        rd.include(request, response);
        out.println("Session has ended.  Please login.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        String userType = (String)session.getAttribute("userType");
        System.out.println(userType);
        if(userType.equals("student")) 
        {}
    }%>
```

I am getting a null pointer exception in using this.
Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like this,

```
<%
String s = (String) application.getAttribute("name");
System.out.println(s);
String userName = (String)session.getAttribute("userName");
if (userName == null) {
    //request.setAttribute("Error", "Session has ended.  Please logenter code herein.");
    RequestDispatcher rd = request
            .getRequestDispatcher("index.hmtl");
    rd.include(request, response);
    out.println("Session has ended.  Please login.");
} 
else 
{
    String userType = (String)session.getAttribute("userType");
    System.out.println(userType);
    if(userType.equals("student")) 
    {}
}%>
```

Comment: What else did i write. You re posted the same jsp code removing the topmost line.

Comment: Exactly. You can directly access session attributes without getting session from request in jsp

Comment: I knew that but I have set the session attributes using servlets session object I am getting null pointer exception in both the cases which you said and which I already did.